# How to check all values in an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have created a multi-dimensional array that contains the values 0 - 2, and I need a way of going through this array to check if any of the values are either 1 or 2. I'm making it so that when there are no 1s or 2s left in the array, the program ends, but I'm unsure of how to check each element.
I've added the array in question below, but this will be filled with values as the program runs.

```
    Dim ownership = New Integer(7, 7) {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                       {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

Is there a way of running through the array to check for the number of each value? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How about looping over each array and checking if each value is either 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like `LINQ`, you can use the [Any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any) method to check whether the array contains *any* value `> 0`:

```
Dim result As Boolean = ownership.OfType(Of Integer).Any(Function(v) v > 0)
```

If `result = True`, there are values `> 0`

If you want a reference of all the elements that have a value `> 0`, you can filter your array using a [Where()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) condition: this *filter* will create a collection of elements that satisfy the condition:

```
Dim FilterResult = ownership.OfType(Of Integer).
                             Select(Function(elm, idx) New With {elm, idx}).
                             Where(Function(arr) arr.elm > 0).ToArray()
```

This query will return an array (it could be a List, using `ToList()` instead of `ToArray()`) of all the elements that have a value `> 0` and their Index (position) inside the `ownership` array.

**Note**:
As commented by [djv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53750799/how-to-check-all-values-in-an-array/53752306#comment94362787_53752306), the `LINQ` query flattens the array indexes.
When a conversion from 1D to 2D indexing is required (using `LINQ` wouldn't matter, the flat index can be used in the queries), you can use this transformation (or something similar):

```
Dim Position2D As (Row As Integer, Col As Integer) =
    (result1(0).idx \ (ownership.GetUpperBound(0) + 1),
     result1(0).idx Mod (ownership.GetUpperBound(1) + 1))

Dim ValueAt2DIndex = ownership(Position2D.Row, Position2D.Col)
```

Comment: I agree 100% that Any() is the way to go. In the second part with idx being the 1D index after OfType, one may want to convert back to the 2D indices using integer division and mod

Comment: @djv  I added a note about this.

Answer (score 0):

So this should help

```
    Dim ownership(,) As Integer = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                                   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

    Dim fndNZ As Boolean = False
    Dim ctZ As Integer = 0
    For x As Integer = ownership.GetLowerBound(0) To ownership.GetUpperBound(0)
        For y As Integer = ownership.GetLowerBound(1) To ownership.GetUpperBound(1)
            If ownership(x, y) <> 0 Then
                fndNZ = True
                Exit For
            Else
                ctZ += 1
            End If
        Next
        If fndNZ Then Exit For
    Next
    If fndNZ Then
        'exit program
    End If
```

There is more than needed but it might help.